# How to define concrete factory beans inheriting from generic factory more elegant in Spring?

Tags: spring, generics, configuration, dependency-injection, factory

Stackoverflow community,

I currently defined a generic factory like this:

```
public class ResourceCrudServiceFactory<E, R extends ResourceSupport> implements FactoryBean<ResourceCrudService<R>> {

    private ObjectMapper mapper;
    private CrudService<E> entityCrudService;
    private BidirectionalResourceAssembler<E, R> assembler;

    @Override
    public ResourceCrudService<R> getObject()
            throws Exception {
        ResourceCrudServiceImpl<E, R> resourceCrudService = 
                new ResourceCrudServiceImpl<E, R>(); 
        resourceCrudService.setMapper(mapper);
        resourceCrudService.setService(entityCrudService);
        resourceCrudService.setAssembler(assembler);
        return resourceCrudService;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return ResourceCrudService.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return true;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setMapper(ObjectMapper mapper) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    public void setEntityCrudService(CrudService<E> entityCrudService) {
        this.entityCrudService = entityCrudService;
    }

    public void setAssembler(
            BidirectionalResourceAssembler<E, R> assembler) {
        this.assembler = assembler;
    }

}
```

To create concrete representations of what the factory produces, I currently subclass the factory like e.g. this

```
@Component(value = "colorTypeResourceServiceFactory")
public class ColorTypeResourceServiceFactory extends ResourceCrudServiceFactory<ColorType, ColorTypeResource> {

    @Override
    @Autowired
    public void setEntityCrudService(CrudService<ColorType> entityCrudService) {
        super.setEntityCrudService(entityCrudService);
    }

    @Override
    @Autowired
    public void setAssembler(
            BidirectionalResourceAssembler<ColorType, ColorTypeResource> assembler) {
        super.setAssembler(assembler);
    }

}
```

If I go on like this, I will end up with something like 80 subclasses of the factory just for the purpose of creating concrete implementations of interfaces. Is there an more elegant way to achieve the same, without all the subclass overhead in Spring DI?

Best regards,
Marius

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found one possible solution: Define concrete beans in one of your @Configuration annotated config classes. E.g.:

```
@ComponentScan
@Configuration
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = HypermediaType.HAL)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJSONDoc
//@EnableWebMvc
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    // LinkConverterService factories
    @Bean
    public LinkConverterService<ItemType> itemTypeLinkConverterServiceFactory(ApplicationContext context) {
        LinkConverterServiceImpl<ItemType> linkConverter = new LinkConverterServiceImpl<ItemType>();
        linkConverter.setService(context.getBean(ItemTypeServiceImpl.class));
        linkConverter.setAssembler(context.getBean(ItemTypeResourceAssembler.class));
        return linkConverter;
    }

    // Resource Crud Service factories
    @Bean
    public ResourceCrudServiceFactory<ColorType, ColorTypeResource> colorTypeResourceServiceFactory(ApplicationContext context) {
        ResourceCrudServiceFactory<ColorType, ColorTypeResource> service = new ResourceCrudServiceFactory<>();
        service.setAssembler(context.getBean(ColorTypeResourceAssembler.class));
        service.setEntityCrudService(context.getBean(ColorTypeServiceImpl.class));
        return service;
    }

    @Bean
    public ResourceCrudServiceFactory<ItemType, ItemTypeResource> itemTypeResourceServiceFactory(ApplicationContext context) {
        ResourceCrudServiceFactory<ItemType, ItemTypeResource> service = new ResourceCrudServiceFactory<>();
        service.setAssembler(context.getBean(ItemTypeResourceAssembler.class));
        service.setEntityCrudService(context.getBean(ItemTypeServiceImpl.class));
        return service;
    }

    @Bean
    public ResourceCrudServiceFactory<ColorFamily, ColorFamilyResource> colorFamilyResourceServiceFactory(ApplicationContext context) {
        ResourceCrudServiceFactory<ColorFamily, ColorFamilyResource> service = new ResourceCrudServiceFactory<>();
        service.setAssembler(context.getBean(ColorFamilyResourceAssembler.class));
        service.setEntityCrudService(context.getBean(ColorFamilyServiceImpl.class));
        return service;
    }

    @Bean
    public ResourceCrudServiceFactory<Item, ItemResource> itemResourceServiceFactory(ApplicationContext context) {
        ResourceCrudServiceFactory<Item, ItemResource> service = new ResourceCrudServiceFactory<>();
        service.setAssembler(context.getBean(ItemResourceAssembler.class));
        service.setEntityCrudService(context.getBean(ItemServiceImpl.class));
        return service;
    }

}
```